# Find an isometry $f :\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ such that $f(\overline{AB}) = \overline {A'B'}$ where d(A,B)=d(A'B')

Tags: geometry

Supposing that I have two line segments $\overline {AB}$, and $\overline {A'B'} $ of equal length in $\Bbb R^3$, I wish to find an isometry $f :\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ such that $f(\overline{AB}) = \overline {A'B'}$.

I essentially need an isometry where $f(A+ t(B-A)) = A' + t(B'-A')$ for $t \in [0,1]$. Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Any rotation or translation is ok</s>
The isometries that preserve length are rotations (including improper ones) and translations, and any combination of those. So what you want is to translate $A'$ to $A$, rotate $AB$ to overlap $A'B'$, then translate everything back to the old $A'$ position

Comment: Although rotations and translations are isometries, they will not always produce the desired coincidence of $f(\overline{AB})$ with $\overline{A'B'}$.